# VBA: Run-Time error '91' (Code working in template but not "new from template")

Tags: vba, templates, runtime-error, selection

My code works when run from the "open" template (Eg. Template.dotm) but not when i use "new from template" (Eg. Document1.docx).

**When run from "Document1" error code prompts**:

*"Run-time error '91' Object variable or With block variable not set"*

**Debugger highlights:**

*Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=129*

**My Code in Microsoft Word Obejcts / This Document:**

> Opens Userform1 when making new document from template:

```
Private Sub Document_New()
    Userform1.Show
End Sub
```

**Code in Userform1**

> EDITED Now "run-time error '438' Object does not supp. property or method."
>
> If CheckBox1 = True it Opens text.docx and pastes its contents in line 129 of this document

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Newdocument As Document
Set NewDocument = ThisDocument            
Dim myDoc As Document
            Set myDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\Stack\Documents\Text.docx", ReadOnly:=False)

         ' do some stuff
         'Opens text document and pastes it in line 129 of this document
          If CheckBox1 = True Then



          myDoc.WholeStory
          myDoc.Copy

          Newdocument.Activate

          Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=129
          Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

          Application.DisplayAlerts = False
          myDoc.Close

      End If

      Unload Me
      Exit Sub

      End Sub



I probably seem clueless in your eyes, but i am new to VBA and still learning. Debugger now highlights the "mydoc.wholestory" with error '438'
```

Comment: do not use `Selection`. as per @braX, define an object and use `myDoc.WholeStory`. ... also define an object for ThisDocument, define it before the myDoc. ... also do not use copy/paste to insert the text

Comment: The problem is that i dont know how to define thisdocument as it has not been saved yet when created from a template. I have edited my original post with yours and @brax  comments taken into consideration. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

Selection.InsertFile FileName:="file path"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a document object.

```
Dim myDoc as Document
Set myDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\Stack\Documents\Text.docx", ReadOnly:=False)

' do some stuff

myDoc.Close
```

Comment: Thank for taking your time to help me :) I have posted my attempt at applying the object up top!

Comment: I can't get it to work for both the open template and new from template now :(